# A very Strange DNS 1 & DNS 2 Entry

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have an issue I've never seen before, 5 computers on network. All have access to the server via remote desktop. Only one has Internet access. Tried setting ips static on the ones not connecting to no avail, finally checked the one that was working normally, and found Ip address was set to automatic, but DNS 1 was set to 8.8.8.8, and DNS 2 was set to 8.8.4.4, when i changed the other computers to those dns settings, they worked perfectly. We have no clue how that dns got set as I am the network admin and do all their computer work. All I can think that there's something at the router level? Or ISP level?

Comment: if the IPs are DHCP, then the DNS entries were almost certainly passed down by the DHCP server (which is probably in your router). The better question though, is why is using googles public dns servers helping you reach a server in your LAN?

Comment: We could still reach the server, just couldn't get internet. The ISP they have, we have always had trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are DNS servers that are easy to remember, and if my memory serves me right, google runs them. While the latency to these might be higher than the one provided by your ISP or sysadmin, they are pretty much guaranteed to work, and many people use them instead if they're having DNS issues.

If these seem to come from nowhere, I'm guessing that someone else was troubleshooting or testing, and set the computers up to use these. Either statically on the computers themselves, or configured the DHCP server to provide them. If the latter, as you are the sysadmin, I encourage you to yell at whoever did this without notifying you.

On a related note: I do that a lot, except I use `4.2.2.2` and `4.2.2.1` instead

Comment: I did try to yell at someone, but no one there knows enough to even get close to changing those entries... I'm thinking those dns entries were there before I took over there and didn't notice. But this is very good information to have, thank you all very much, I've learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying the IP addressing for the workstation was dynamic, but the DNS settings were static.  The IP addresses you mentioned are the well-known Google public DNS records.

There are only two ways this could have happened:

- Somebody manually configured the DNS entries
- At some point there was a Group Policy that set the DNS statically to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

There are DHCP options for DNS, but nothing at that level, the router level, or ISP level could alter Windows to set a *static* entry like this.